# C# Remove unwanted characters from a string

Tags: c#, string, char

I have looked into other posts, and all of them have known unwanted characters.
In my case, I have a bunch of characters that I want, and I only want to keep those.

My code is way too messy:

```
private string RemoveUnwantedChar(string input)
{
    string correctString = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        if (char.IsDigit(input[i]) || input[i] == '.' || input[i] == '-' || input[i] == 'n'
                || input[i] == 'u' || input[i] == 'm' || input[i] == 'k' || input[i] == 'M'
                || input[i] == 'G' || input[i] == 'H' || input[i] == 'z' || input[i] == 'V'
                || input[i] == 's' || input[i] == '%')
            correctString += input[i];
    }
    return correctString;
}
```

Characters that I want: `0123456789` and `numkMGHzVs%-.`

Comment: This is more a question for: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Oh I didnt know about that community. Thanks!

Comment: you could theoretically use a regex operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
// create a lookup hashset
private static HashSet<char> _allowedChars = new HashSet<char>("0123456789numkMGHzVs%-.".ToArray());

private string FilterString(string str)
{
    // tempbuffer
    char[] buffer = new char[str.Length];
    int index = 0;

    // check each character
    foreach (var ch in str)
        if (_allowedChars.Contains(ch))
            buffer[index++] = ch;

    // return the new string.
    return new String(buffer, 0, index);
}
```

So the trick is, create a hashset to validate each character. The 'messy' way, like you said, is creating new strings and will fragement memory. Also try to avoid many nested `if` statements. (like you want to avoid)

---

If you like linq, you could do something like:

```
// create a lookup hashset
private static HashSet<char> _allowedChars = new HashSet<char>("0123456789numkMGHzVs%-.".ToArray());

private string FilterString2(string str)
{
    return new String(
        str.Where(ch => _allowedChars.Contains(ch)).ToArray());
}
```

But this will make it less readable..

Comment: Thanks! That is sort of what I want, an char array of all the wanted characters, which has better readability. Btw, why HashSet? Will a normal 1D char array work?

Comment: Sure, with these few characters, a normal array will work fine.

Comment: @Liren Because arrays and lists in general are not for searching, while sets and dictionaries are specifically for searching.

Comment: ++ but the LINQ approach doesn't need the first `str.ToArray()`

Answer (score 8):

You can use LINQ:

```
var allowedChars = "0123456789numkMGHzVs";
var result = String.Join("", input.Where(c => allowedChars.Any(x => x == c)));
```

Another option:

```
var result = String.Join("", str.Where(c => allowedChars.Contains(c)));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `String.Concat` + `Enumerable.Where` with `HashSet<T>.Contains`:

```
HashSet<char> AllowedChars = new HashSet<char>("0123456789numkMGHzVs%-.");
private string RemoveUnwantedChar(string input)
{
    return string.Concat(input.Where(AllowedChars.Contains));
}
```

Here's another efficient aproach using a `StringBuilder` and a `HashSet<T>`:

```
HashSet<char> AllowedChars = new HashSet<char>("0123456789numkMGHzVs%-.");
private string RemoveUnwantedChar(string input)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input.Length);
    foreach (char c in input)
        if (AllowedChars.Contains(c))
            sb.Append(c);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I like the first method. passing the `Contains` method to the `Where` statement.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using LINQ you could do this:

```
char[] validChars = "0123456789numkMGHzVs%-.".ToArray();
var newString = "Teststring012";

string filtered = string.Join("", newString.Where(x => validChars.Contains(x)));
```

Answer (score 1):

I like this clear and readable Regex solution.

```
public string RemoveUnwantedChar(string input) {
    return Regex.Replace(input, "[^0-9numkMGHzVs%\\-.]", "");
}
```